# How to write Unit test case for below function

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

Below code is working but code is not written as it is supposed to do. Because function is returning something but I as per my unit test function is returning value

TS Code:

```
checkSelectionFromDeletable() {
    return this.numbersFacade.selectedRows$.pipe(
      map(selectedRowCapsule =>
        selectedRowCapsule?.selectedRows.find(x => x.owner || x.mainNumberFlag)
      )
    );
 }
```

spec.ts

```
it('should test checkSelectionFromDeletable', () => {
      const rowData  = of({
        phoneNumber: '12345678',
        extension: '',
        numberType: 'MAIN',
        state: 'US',
        location: '',
        locationId: '',
        mainNumberFlag: false,
        tollFreeFlag: false,
        owner: 'test'
      } as ICallNumberVM)
      component.checkSelectionFromDeletable();
      numbersFacade.selectedRows$.subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).toEqual(rowData);
      });
    });
```

Comment: What's `this.numbersFacade.selectedRows`? Show the code

Comment: So did yo get an error with this unit-test case ?

Answer (score 1):

The method you want to test uses an external member (`this.numbersFacade.selectedRows$`) and returns an observable. That means you should:

1. Initialize `this.numbersFacade.selectedRows$` at the beginning of the test (the **Arrange** part).
2. Call `checkSelectionFromDeletable()` and save returned observable (the **Act** part).
3. Subscribe to observable just returned and expect each of the elements in the collection to have either owner or flag defined (the **Assert** part).

For example:

```
it('should test checkSelectionFromDeletable', () => {
  const inputRows = [{ ... }, .........., { ... }];
  this.numbersFacade.selectedRows$ = of(inputRows); // Arrange
  const actualRows$ = component.checkSelectionFromDeletable(); // Act
  actualRows$.subscribe(actualRows => {
    const expectedRows = [{ ... }, .........., { ... }]; // Only those elements from 'inputRows' each of which having either owner or flag defined.
    // Assert: here you should expect 'expectedRows' to deeply equals 'actualRows'.
  });
});
```